# Git Merge - Not merging all changes from remote branch

Tags: git

I branched from master and created a branch called extra_work. Then I made lots of changes to master which included removing some files as well. Later now when I tried to merge the branch 'extra_work' into the master, it is not merging it entirely. 
It is not adding the files that I removed in master, basically all the work that I had undone, now I want it back into my master.
How do I merge these two branches so that all the extra files/work from my 'extra_work' branch merges into master. 
Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Rebase your `extra_work` branch against `master`. This will rewind your `extra_work` branch to the state when you branched, and apply the commits from `master` to `extra_work`. It will then replay all the commits from `extra_work` back onto itself. If you inspect `git log`  after that you will see the commits from `master` further back in the history of the branch. You should then be able to merge to `master` with no problems.

```
git rebase master
```

Comment: Rebases are how changes should pass from the top of hierarchy downwards and merges are how they flow back upwards.

https://www.derekgourlay.com/blog/git-when-to-merge-vs-when-to-rebase/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem very recently while doing major refactoring. I solved the problem by doing `git rebase`, from `master` rebasing onto `extra-work`. I don't fully understand this whole thing, but the merge went terribly (like you experienced) but rebasing in this particular direction was very easy. See the git book on rebasing: http://book.git-scm.com/4_rebasing.html